# How send emails to different recipients based on the date in the cells in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Please help me out in this, I've been trying to find the script from last week but positive results.

My requirement is as below,

I would like to send service confirmation emails to employees which who has completed 180 days (DOJ>180) from their date of joining and after mail sent, status should be updated in the other column like "sent\Confirmed". I don't want to run that script everyday, it should go automatically based on the system date. Seems like simple requirement but it can save lot of time.

I'm attaching a sample data link below,

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IihLKfo5eP3DoVEQ8_-RmipOCHLXARSg2DMpYfUhTMI/edit#gid=0
[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlePI.png)
Any data sample or clarification on requirement please reply.

It'll be really appreciated if anyone help on this.

Regards
Gopik

Comment: FYI your shared spreadsheet doesn't have "anyone with a link can view" permission enabled.

Comment: I just enabled it, really sorry for that.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic starting script for you.  I haven't debugged any of this code although the editor went ahead and saved it without a problem.  I don't know what you want the email to say. It's based upon the column positions in your provided spreadsheet.  I named that sheet 'ConfirmationEmails'.

```
function sendConfirmationEmails()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht = ss.getSheetByName('ConfirmationEmails');
  var datrng = sht.getDataRange();
  var datAry = rng.getValues();
  var day = 86400000;
  var today = new Date().getTime();
  for(var i = 0;i<datAry.length;i++)
  {
    if(datAry[i][5] == 'Not Confirmed')
    {
      if(isDate(datAry[i][3]) && (((today - new Date(datAry[i][3]).getTime())/day) > 150 ))
      {
        if(GmailApp.sendEmail(datAry[i][2], 'Confirmation Email', 'It\'s been greater than 150 days since you\'ve joined our organization'))
        {
          datAry[i][5]='Confirmed';//You might like to write to the cells here instead of waiting until the end.
          datAry[i][4]=new Date();
        }
        
      }
  
    }
  }
  datrng.setValues(datAry);
}

function isDate (x)  
{ 
  return (null != x) && !isNaN(x) && ("undefined" !== typeof x.getDate); 
}
```

As far as the setting up of triggers to run this every day.  Go to the edit menu of the code editor to setup you trigger and you may wish to read about triggers in the API.

Comment: Hey, this is really helpful. I've changed the code according to my requirement and working perfectly. Thank you so much for your efforts.